# Is there something i can change to make it work like how it's supposed to

Tags: java

There is this program that asks me to write a java program that asks the user to type a positive number n and prints the sum of odd numbers using while loop: 1+3+5+7…+(2n-1).
Example : If the input is 4, then the program will print 16

so what i did is made this code :

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter  a positive number :");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (i<=n)
        {
            sum += i ;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

And the program is not working like how the question wants it to be like

Comment: Hello Rare and welcome to stack overflow! :-) fist of all the title of your question should be more informative: something like "How to sum the first 2n-1 odd numbers in Java". Now, talking about your code: your loop should reach 2n-1 and also it should skip even numbers. Good luck studying coding! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `i += 2;` which is same as `i = i + 2;`, instead of using `i++;`.

**But this won't give you the output you expect. So, there has to be made several changes in your code to get the expected result.**

- First initialise the value of `i` to 1.

```
int i = 1;
```

- Then, change the `while loop` statement to,

```
while (i <= (2 * n - 1)){
      // Your Code
}
```

- Finally, use `i += 2;` as your increment statement.

***The full code is shown below.***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter  a positive number :");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int i = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        while (i<=(2 * n - 1))
        {
            sum += i ;
            i += 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `-1` or the `( )`, so `while (i < 2 * n)` is simpler. Using `(2n-1)` does however fit the upper limit of the sequence shown in the question, so either way is good.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, it would be simpler if we changed the condition to `while (i < 2 * n)`. But, when analysing the code, it will make it difficult to understand the code in later references. So, I think it is better to leave the condition as it was because it makes the logic more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized `i` wrong. It should start from 1 since you want to add only odd numbers. Also increase `i` by 2 units using `+=2`. Another problem is with the while loop condition. The last number in the sequence will be 2n-1 and not n. So the program will be:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter  a positive number :");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int i = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        while (i <= (2 * n - 1)) // Here is the new condition for last number...
        {
            sum += i ;
            i+=2; // Here goes the 2 unit increment...
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question says: *"If the input is 4, then the program will print 16"*, which is `1+3+5+7`, i.e. the sum of the first 4 odd numbers. Making the change suggested here will calculate `1+3=4`, i.e. not the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I nearly forgot that. I've made the necessary edits. Now, kindly remove the downvote @Andreas

Comment: Sure, once you explain the change, and modify the code so it actually compiles. Of course, your answer will just end up being a duplicate of [answer by Alpha Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196500/5221149).

Comment: I agree, 'cause while I was typing I wasn't aware of Alpha Beta's answer. It only updated after I posted. I might delete my answer if you want but atleast remove your downvote now that I've explained things in much more crisp and shorter manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a variable like **odd** and **increase its value by 2** in every iteration.
Also,

> you should run the loop less than n times

because you start the loop from 0. Then I hope you will get your desired answer. Here is the sample code which may help you to understand.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter  a positive number :");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int odd = 1;
        while (i<n)
        {
            sum += odd ;
            odd += 2;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```